# how can we query foreign key and get results of objects which are connected to foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How can I can use managers to query my foreign key and then retrieve objects that are connected to foreign key?

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def title_count(self,keyword):
        return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def category_count(self):
        return self.filter(category__icontains=python).count()
class Category(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Enquiry(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category ,default=False,blank=False)
    detail=models.TextField()
    objects = BookManager()
    objects=CategoryManager()
    # tags=models.ChoiceField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I tried to use category manager but it gave me a strange error. 
I just want to know how exactly we can get the objects that are connected with category foriegn-key and show them as list to the users.

Comment: In `Enquiry` model you can just do `Enquiry.objects.filter(category.title='categorytitle')` and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both the **title_count** and **category_count** methods under one **Manager**. When filtering through a **ForeignKey**, your **field lookup** needs to specify the name of the field you're trying to filter on, else it will assume you're querying the **ID** field. So instead of **category__icontains**, you would do **category__title__icontains**.

Another note, in newer versions of **Django**, you are required to specify the **on_delete** parameter when defining a **ForeignKey**.

This is a working example of what I think you're trying to accomplish.

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def title_count(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()

    def category_count(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(category__title__icontains=keyword).count()


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Enquiry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 default=False,
                                 blank=False,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()
    books = BookManager()

    # tags=models.ChoiceField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
Enquiry.books.category_count('python')
Enquiry.books.title_count('test')
```